# Why NSMutableDictionary console show different values?

Tags: ios, iphone, localytics

```
NSString* promocode = @"DISCOUNT20";
[attributes setObject:[promocode length]>0?promocode:@"Valid Promo Code" forKey:ATT_BookingPromoCode];
At Console:
{
  "Promo Code" = DISCOUNT20;
}

NSString* promocode = @"Jan20%";
[attributes setObject:[promocode length]>0?promocode:@"Valid Promo Code" forKey:ATT_BookingPromoCode];
At Console:
{
  "Promo Code" = "Jan20%";
}
```

why getting Quoted difference ?
what i should do to avoid this ?

Need to know difference because

I am preparing Dictionary for Localytics, at some cases i am getting [Unspecified] values. may be this is happening because "value" is not getting considered.. as [Unspecifed] comes only when you are sending empty or null values. but i have already set condition for that. though i am getting unspecified values at localytics. thats why me be error at preparing dictionary which i am sending.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you worrying about the console output ? Why you need to remove the quote from console output ?

Comment: I am preparing Dictionary for Localytics,  at some cases i am getting [Unspecified] values. may be this is happening because "value" is not getting considered.. 
as [Unspecifed] comes only when you are sending empty or null values. 
but i have already set condition for that. though i am getting unspecified values at localytics. thats why me be error at preparing dictionary which i am sending.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that

```
NSString* promocode = @"Jan20%";
```

contains a % (character used to escape) and that you actually printed the dictionary and not the string object

as an example

```
NSDictionary *d = @{@"test1":@"Discount20", @"test2":@"jan20%"};
for (id key in [d allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [d objectForKey:key]);
}
/* Output :
   Discount20
   jan20%
*/
NSLog(@"%@",d);
/* Output     
   {
    test1 = Discount20;
    test2 = "jan20%";
}
```

Comment: Why does the key have quotes?  As both versions of `promocode` are strings, why doesn't the first value have quotes?  It doesn't make alot of sense.

Comment: how do you declare ATT_BookingPromoCode

Comment: What I'm saying is the console output is inconsistent. It's also not clear why there are quotes with the value when `%` is within it given the string is not being used in "printf()" way, which is where `%` is significant.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", <dictionary>) call the description method on that object, that simply wraps things in quotes for displaying those having non-alphanumeric characters in them. Also NSLog should be only used for debugging purpose, so the fact that there are quotes is not really a big deal